# How to see console statements in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

This is a super noob question but how can I see my `console.log()` statements in Firefox? I've opened up the developer tools by running `cmd` + `shift` + `i` but can't see any of my `console.log()` statements. When I use chrome, I can correctly see my `console.log()` so I know I must not be enabling a setting or something in Firefox.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Note: Not sure if it makes a difference but I'm also using reactjs

Comment: Maybe show some code? Also, put an `alert` in to make sure the code is actually executed. (Just in case)

Comment: @KerwinSneijders thanks for the tip! Turns out the `alert` isn't being called in Firefox but is working properly in Chrome. This leads me to think that my code is behaving differently from browser to browser. Thanks for the help everyone. Closing this since it doesn't seem to be a Firefox - console related issue.

Answer (score 1):

After opening the Developer Tools, click the Console tab. Ensure that the log option is selected in the output filters.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I've ensured that the log option is selected in the output filters but still cannot seem to see my console.log statements :-(